# ActionController UnknownFormat Error in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem in rails.

1. View (index.html.erb)

   ```
   <div id="container" style="margin:0 auto;">
     <div style="float:left; height: 300px; width: 300px" align="center">

       <%= form_tag("/java/select", :method => "post", :remote => true) do %>
         Deivce1 <%= radio_button_tag "devices", "1"%><br>
         Deivce2 <%= radio_button_tag "devices", "2"%><br>
         Deivce3 <%= radio_button_tag "devices", "3"%><br>

         <%= submit_tag "On/Off" %>
       <% end %>

     </div>

   </div>

   <div id="statelist"></div>
   ```
2. Controller(java_controller.rb)

   ```
   class JavaController < ApplicationController

   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

       def select
         @device = params[:devices]
         respond_to do|format|
            format.js
         end
       end
   end
   ```
3. js file (select.js.erb)

   ```
   $('#statelist').empty().append('<%= j render 'statelist'%>');
   ```
4. html file (_statelist.html.erb)

   ```
   Selected device is <%= @device %>
   ```
5. root file (rootes.rb)

   ```
   root "java#index"
   post "java/select" => "java#select"
   ```

I think I have all components to operate ajax. Also, I usually used similar grammars in advance.

However, in this case, when I clicked the "On/Off" button, the Unknownformat error message appear in the web page.

This error indicated "respond_to do |format|" line at controller.

What is the problem ?? Thank you for your attention.

---

- Log...

  ```
  Started POST "/java/select" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-14 17:48:55 +0900
  Processing by JavaController#select as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "devices"=>"2", "commit"=>"On/Off"}
  Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 6ms

  ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
    app/controllers/java_controller.rb:14:in `select'


    Rendered /usr/lib/jruby/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (6.0ms)
    Rendered /usr/lib/jruby/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (14.0ms)
    Rendered /usr/lib/jruby/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (19.0ms)
    Rendered /usr/lib/jruby/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (291.0ms)
  ```

Comment: Do you have a copy of your `logs` for this call?

Comment: Can't really see anything wrong.  The only thing is this line `respond_to do|format|` is that on line 14?  I'm wondering if it's because you have no space between the `do` and the `|format|`

Comment: Yes, that is on line 14. Also, I gave a space between do and |foramt|, but, there was same error.

Comment: It's because your request is going through as HTML, and you don't have any `format.html` support -- can you add format.html to your controller & run the request again? This will allow us to test whether this is the problem

Comment: I tried format.html. when I run request, template missing error appeared. However I don't want to load new page. I just want update the current page. Thank you.

Comment: That's good - it means we know the problem is the request is being sent as `html` - it needs to be sent as `js`

Comment: Aha~ I understand the problem . But how can I resolve this problem??

Comment: So does this request go through ajax, or does your page actually refresh? What I'm trying to determine is whether your Javascript has been loaded on the page -- as this type of problem would typically be caused by a lack of having java enabled / available for your app

Comment: Do you have a model for javaController?

Comment: @Papouche Guinslyzinho - I have a model which don't implement activeRecord.

Comment: &Rich Peck - sorry..What is mean of a lack of having java enable/available for your app??

Comment: Ok on your source file of your html , make sure you have jquery and jquery_ujs cause I have a the right request and the proper result when I do your app (gist) https://gist.github.com/guinslym/67f3e8b15b85d471c042

Comment: @Papouche Guinslyzinho - How can I check that? I saw "require jquery / require jquery_ujs" in [rails app]/app/assets/javascripts/application.js. Is this right?

Comment: But, there are same error..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59344/discussion-between-papouche-guinslyzinho-and-jy-choi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the

```
 respond_to do|format|
     format.js
  end
```

block. In your case it will load the select.js partial automatically according to the rails defaults. I'm not sure, but perhaps you will need to change the path to

```
/java/select.js
```

also